# SQL Server transactional replication process and error

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I need to setup a replication.

1. Which replication is better if I want to keep my data updated in the second server as soon as new data is pushed into the primary server.
2. I tried setting up by clicking on New Publication and got error message:-

[image]

So I found I need to use sp_addserver. How does it work, In which table it will add the server name. How will it affect my current setup if I change the server name. Will my APIs or other services connected to this server will start failing if I chnage the server name.

3. A step by step guide for whole replication setup with details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Transactional Replication the changes that occur on the Publisher will replicate to the subscriber, not instantly, but usually fairly quickly.  If you have no need for changes made at the subscriber to replicate back to the publisher, or replicate anywhere else, then Transactional Replication could be the best selection for you.
However, if you want ALL changes made to the primary to also occur on a replica, and the replica can be read-only, then AlwaysOn Availability Group could be the best solution for you.
To setup transactional replication you can follow the wizard and it will guide you step-by-step.  The following youtube video will walk you through it as well https://youtu.be/sT2RQKlhU20

Comment: Thank you @stacylaray...this information is good. How about snapshot replication ? My other question was like how is it going to affect my current setup if I change my server name ?

Comment: Those are completely different questions that should be asked on their own.  What do you mean by "How about snapshot replication?"  Please be more specific with your questions.

Comment: Okay stacylaray..atleast let me knwo how will it affect my current setup If I change my server name ?

Comment: What is your current setup?

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause might be :

This error has been observed on a server that had been renamed after the original installation of SQL Server, and where the SQL Server configuration function ‘@@SERVERNAME’ still returned the original name of the server. This can be confirmed by:

select @@SERVERNAME
 go

This should return the name of the server. If it does not then follow the procedure below to correct it.

Please check these links below :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212032/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-t

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sqlserver/replication_requires_actual_server_name.htm

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/18/sql-server-fix-replication-error-sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-the-server/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4d1d008-05f5-46f2-a145-347cbf4d9e5c/sql-server-replication-requires-the-actual-server-name-to-make-a-connection-to-the-server-specify?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: Yes, Thank you!!!..this is good. My other question was like how is it going to affect my current setup if I change my server name ?